# Unable to find a Ruby executable

Tags: ruby

I tried installing Aptana Studio 3, but when I tried running it I got an error saying

**"Unable to find a Ruby executable."**

Here's a Picture:

[image: http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/sin-titulo-422822.png]

Comment: At the risk of asking a stupid question, do you have Ruby installed on your computer? What operating system are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Aptana properly configured to run ruby? I know with python you have to have to manually set up a python environment in the settings menu. That's if you didn't set it up when you created the project in Aptana. And to complement the comment above, You should check to make sure that ruby is properly installed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm used to Visual C # and C + + and not the same as ruby

Comment: Your welcome, that's fine.